# C output too long

Tags: c, memory-management, output

I have a question about my little c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int c, len;
    int max = 100;
    char *buffer = malloc(max);

    for (len = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; len++) {
        buffer[len] = c;
        if (len == max - 1) {
            buffer = realloc(buffer, (len + max));
            if (buffer == NULL) {
                printf("Error: Out of memory!\n");
                return 1;
            }
            max += 100;
        }
    }
    buffer[len] = '\0';

    for (; len >= 0; --len) {
        printf("%c", buffer[len]);
    }                                    

    printf("\n");
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

My task is to write a program which inserts a text and gives a backwards output of the text.
If there happens to be a problem with the allocated memory an error message should occur. 
According to my test report from university the first lines of the output are 1 character too long, I can't determine the reason for this problem and I'm seeking for some advice and help

Comment: `for (; len >= 0; --len)` --> `for (--len; len >= 0; --len)`, `max += 100;` --> `max += len;` or `(len + max)` --> `(max + 100)`

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem @BLUEPIXY

Comment: You could also do this by calling main recursively and you could not need to allocate memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should understand your problem. You have the following diagnostic:

> the first lines of the output are 1 character too long

This is not enough! You should make a specific example. If you give your program some small input, e.g. `abc`, what will it output? And what should it output? This is less abstract than "1 character too long", and possible to debug.

---

Your program has an off-by-one bug:

```
buffer[len] = '\0';
...
   printf("%c", buffer[len]);
```

The first character it will output will be a null character `\0`. It may not be visible on screen (it's an ["unprintable"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) character), so to debug this you better make your output more verbose, like this:

```
   printf("Character '%c', whose code is %d\n", buffer[len], buffer[len]);
```

Note the following features that make debugging easier:

- Apostrophes around the printed character will make it clear where your code outputs a space
- Verbose format will make it clear how many characters your code outputs
- Printing the character a second time as integer (`%d`) will output its code and will help you debug unprintable characters

---

Your program has more than one bug. Use the above ideas to reproduce and isolate bugs one by one. Please also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).